# Parse a line containing a sequence of entries, inferring data

Tags: python, regex

I tried every possible pattern, but still finding difficulty. Any help please?

So i have this string : `'C+11.,18.,25.6.,2.,23.7.,27.8.23'`

I want my regex to extract the days numbers ( they are situated before every month), and also that are only related to that specific month. Or days in between two months that belong only to the month after days.

Example:

Case1: days of month 6 that are before it |

Case2: days of month 7 that are after month 6. The month is defined as: `*r'\.\d{1}\\.'*` For example 6, 7, and 8 are months here. and any number before them is its days.

Code:

```
import re
captured_pattern = "C+11.,18.,25.6.,2.,23.7.,27.8.23"
pattern = r'(\d{1,2})\.(?=(\d{1})\.(?!.*,\d{1,}\.6))'
matches = re.findall(pattern, captured_pattern)
print(matches)
OUTPUT : [('25', '6'), ('23', '7'), ('27', '8')]
```

The days are defined as:

Example: 11.,18.,25 are days of the month 6 (juin). 2.,23 are days of month 7 (july).

The year is defined in the last part as two-digit format. 23

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @PeterWood what do you mean ? I referred to python because i am using its regex on this issue.

Comment: Please read [mre]

Comment: What should happen to the 23 at the end?

Comment: @9769953 that i already taken care of by this pattern : pattern = f'({day_before_month})'+ r'\.'+ re.escape(str(value)). value here is the month in the pattern of the full year. other are a bit tricky. but the last one's pattern is obvious

Comment: @9769953 28.8.23  Since month is defined \.\d{1}\. and days will be before this month, so 27 here is the day of month 8 in year 2023. the year is only present one time in the last date, because the pattern of such strings, always ends with year. others are just specific days in month.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify in your question that that last value is the year (in two-digit form), and that that is where the string stops. Because that is not obvious, since the string format is not obvious in itself.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @Cow my desires output would be : [('days', 'month'), ('days', 'month'), ('days', 'month'.'year 23')]. however i am finding it hard, to capture all days for that specific month. like in the code example.

Comment: If a fancy regular expression can't solve the problem for you, I'd go the straightforward way: strip off the "C+" and similar strings, split the string on the comma, iterate over each part, split each part by the period character, if there is just one non-zero length item, add it to a list or set of days (converted to int), if there are two, add the list or set to a dict with the second/month integer as key.

Comment: Do you *have* to use only regex for this?

Comment: @Cow No. I can use whatever i want.

Comment: @9769953 I will surely try that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
string = "C+11.,18.,25.6.,2.,23.7.,27.8.23"
# Remove anything that is not a digit, comma or period
cleaned = re.sub(r'[^\d,.]+', '', string)
matches = {}
days = []
for part in cleaned.split(','):
    day, month, *_ = part.split('.')
    days.append(int(day))
    if month:
        matches[int(month)] = days
        days = []
```

Result:

```
{6: [11, 18, 25], 7: [2, 23], 8: [27]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can match the text portions with days up to their respective month and use

```py
import re
s="C+11.,18.,25.6.,2.,23.7.,27.8.23"
rx = r'\b(\d{1,2}(?:\.,\d+)*)\.(\d{1,2})\b'
results = [(days.split('.,'),month,) for days, month in re.findall(rx, s)]
print(results)
# => [(['11', '18', '25'], '6'), (['2', '23'], '7'), (['27'], '8')]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/hkcPLV). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PxQNeE/1). Note that the days regex part can be defined as `(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])` and the month regex part can be further precised as `(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])`.

*Regex details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\d{1,2}(?:\.,\d+)*)` - Group 1: one or two digits, and then zero or more repetitions of `.,` + one or more digits
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `(\d{1,2})` - Group 2 (month): one or two digits
- `\b` - a word boundary

Answer (score 1):

If the parsing task is too complex for a single regex, use a custom parser and relegate regexes to simpler parts.

**Regexes are good for parsing simple data structures but are not good for parsing data sequences (and plain cannot parse recursive structures like arbitrarily-deep nesting).** They are also unable to do any custom processing logic like inferring parts of data in an application-specific way.

```
import re
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MutableDate:
    day = None
    month = None
    year = None

def parse(data: str):

  # split off the prefix
  data = re.match(r'[^+]+\+(.*)',data).group(1)

  # a regex for each entry
  entry_re = re.compile(r'(?P<day>\d+)\.(?:(?P<month>\d+)\.(?P<year>\d+)?)?')

  # parse the sequence into separate entries
  entries=data.split(',')

  # parse individual entries
  result=[]
  for entry in entries:
    m = entry_re.match(entry)
    result.append(MutableDate(**m.groupdict()))

  # process the parsed data with your custom logic
  # (infer missing parts of dates)
  last_month_entry = last_year_entry = None
  for i,entry in enumerate(result):
    current_month = entry.month
    if current_month != None:
      for earlier_entry in result[i-1:last_month_entry:-1]:
        earlier_entry.month = current_month
      last_month_entry = i

    current_year = entry.year
    if current_year != None:
       for earlier_entry in result[i-1:last_year_entry:-1]:
         earlier_entry.year = current_year
       last_year_entry = i

  # optionally convert all entries in the result to `datetime.date`.
  # this would have a useful side effect of validating the dates

  return result
```

For your data, this returns:

```
[MutableDate(day='11', month='6', year='23'),
 MutableDate(day='18', month='6', year='23'),
 MutableDate(day='25', month='6', year='23'),
 MutableDate(day='2', month='7', year='23'),
 MutableDate(day='23', month='7', year='23'),
 MutableDate(day='27', month='8', year='23')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion:

```
import re
captured_pattern = "C+11.,18.,25.6.,2.,23.7.,27.8.23"
matches = [tuple(f"{v}.{value}".split(".")) for key,value in re.findall(r"\b(\d{1,2}(?:\.,\d+)*|(?:\.,\d+)\.\d)\.(\d{1,2})\b", captured_pattern) for v in key.split(".,") if v]
print(matches)
```

Result:

```
[('11', '6'), ('18', '6'), ('25', '6'), ('2', '7'), ('23', '7'), ('27', '8', '23')]
```

Link to [RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/s9d2vu/1)